# How to render another controller method by image link using yii2?

Tags: yii2

following code will render an image:

```
<?= Html::img('@web/img/accept_all_you_see-wallpaper-1680x1050.jpg', ['alt' => 'PicNotFound', 'class' => 'scale-with-grid wp-post-image', 'style' => 'width:960;height:700']); ?>
```

following code will render an image as a link

```
<?= Html::a('', Yii::getAlias('@web') . '/img/pic1.jpg', ['target' => '_blank', 'alt' => 'PicNotFound', 'class' => 'icon-search']) ?>
```

How to code, if I want render another Conroller method by clicking on an image?
Following code will implement my intention by bootstrap icon, not by image!

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <?= Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span>', ['/dateianhang/dateianhang/index'], ['title' => 'Anlagen anzeigen', 'data' => ['pjax' => '0']]); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?= Html::a(
    Html::img(
        '@web/img/accept_all_you_see-wallpaper-1680x1050.jpg',
        ['alt' => 'PicNotFound', 'class' => 'scale-with-grid wp-post-image', 'style' => 'width:960;height:700']
    ),
    ['/dateianhang/dateianhang/index'],
    ['title' => 'Anlagen anzeigen', 'data' => ['pjax' => '0']]
) ?>
```

Comment: Works great. Thx a lot for ur solution. Reputation points for ur efforts have been given by me 2 U !

Comment: No, if you don't need it, don't use it. It mostly depends on your layout and styles. Usually `Html::img( '@web/img/accept_all_you_see-wallpaper-1680x1050.jpg')` is enough for image.